# Using vuejs to insert dynamic url inside of a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to dynamic bind an image path inside a method. It seems possible, but I'm not sure if I am applying the code correctly. Can someone take a peak? Basically I am trying to get the selected image from the model instead of hardcode the url inside of the onscreen text.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  imagesPathArr:[],
    selectedImage2: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg',
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    greet: function (event) {
    alert("test");
        window.Core.ExecuteCommand({ 
    name: 'mceInsertContent',
    value: '<img :src="selectedImage2" width="600px;" alt="text here" />'
}, 'topicContent$html');
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="greet">Click ME</button>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding the variable in the text.

```
'<img :src="' + this.selectedImage2 + '" width="600px;" alt="text here" />'
```

Or, using backticks:

```
`<img :src="${this.selectedImage2}" width="600px;" alt="text here" />`
```